# Understanding a simple two-fermion repulsion model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions

Consider a fermion model with repulsion $U$
$$H=A(n_a+n_b)+Un_an_b$$
with $n_a=a^\dagger a$ and $n_b=b^\dagger b$ for the two kinds of fermions.
Its partition function with chemical potential $\mu$ is $$Z=1+2e^{-\beta(A-\mu)}+e^{-\beta(2(A-\mu)+U)}.$$
Then one can easily find the average total fermion number $$N=\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial\ln Z}{\partial\mu},$$ which under the zero-temperature limit ($\beta\rightarrow\infty$) gives $$N(T=0)=\theta(\mu-A)+\theta(\mu-A-U).$$
Therefore, as $\mu$ grows from 0, $N$ changes from 0 to 1 at $\mu=A$ and then from 1 to 2 at $\mu=A+U$. The calculation and result is flawless and found also in textbooks.

But why is the second jump at $\mu=A+U$ rather than $\mu=A+U/2$? How to understand it? (I naively think the repulsion energy should be halved for one fermion as the total energy is $2A+U$.)

Comment: Why should the second jump be at $A + U/2$? The energy cost (from the Hamiltonian) for the first particle is $A$, then the second is $A+U$. So, I would think if $\mu>A$ it's favorable to add the first, if $\mu>A+U$ it's favorable to add the second as well.